# Kth Power Coprime with N

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers

Given two integers $N$ and $K$. A function of $N$ and $K$  the sum of K'th powers of the positive numbers, which are coprime with N and also not greater than N.

E.g., the Function value for $N=6$ and $K=3$ equals to $1^3 + 5^3 = 126$.

I want to calculate value of this Function in case $N$ and $K$ are big integers. As far as value could be extremely huge, I need to do all the calculation under modulo $M$.

EXAMPLE :

Say $N=5,K=2,M=100$

Then the answer is $(1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2)\bmod 100 = 30$.

Comment: I get the impression that this question is from some programming competition (they typically throw in the modular reduction to avoid bigint considerations, not because the modular value is actually of interest).

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is from a [programming competition](http://codechef.com/LTIME07/problems/SFUNC), I'll not be providing full answer but just a few hints to *one* possible approach to the problem (not necessarily the optimal one):

- Although it is not really necessary, the actual problem statement specifies that $K$ is rather small. There are nice explicit formulas for summing $K$-th powers of integers from $1$ to $N$; it's not too difficult to find them [online](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) or actually derive them yourself.
- Summing over the numbers which are coprime to $N$ is the same as summing over all integers and removing those which are not coprime to it = those which have some factor in common with $N$.
- $N$ is small enough to be fully factorable by [trial division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division).
- [Inclusion-exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) is your friend.
- As an example, for $N=6$ and $K=2$, we have $1^2 + 5^2 = (1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+5^2+6^2) - (2^2+4^2+6^2) - (3^2+6^2) + 6^2$.

Comment: If you KNOW that it is from a competition why provide a hint?

Comment: @Phira Because the [contest it was part of](http://www.codechef.com/LTIME07/) is over now and submissions by the contestants are public. Since the editorials are not public yet, the hints provide some suggestions as to how the problem could have been tackled without providing the full solution and ruining the fun for those who want to practice on it but are stuck.